# How does an application discover the value of scale?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created a docker-compose project which includes multiple `unit` instances and a single `processor` item.  I can invoke my `docker-compose.yml` file with `docker-compose up --scale unit=4` but I want the `processor` object to interact separately with each `unit` instance.  Is there a way I can retrieve the value of `scale` to pass somehow to the `processor` object?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer. I think a typical solution would be to have your `unit` instances use some mechanism to register themselves with the `processor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use env for that and pass it to `processor` service https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment

Also, check https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution for managing replicas within config file